# JOLT Transformation --- Adding Header From The Element

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the JSON object below :

```json
{
  "trans-details": [
    {
      "customernum": "41700013",
      "crmordernum": "SO-000048949",
      "customerordernum": "Over delivery BRAZI",
      "itemnumber": "A0002309953",
      "status": 3,
      "pagecount": 64,
      "orderstatus": 3,
      "requestedqty": 0
    },
    {
      "customernum": "41700013",
      "crmordernum": "SO-000049948",
      "customerordernum": "Over delivery test ZA",
      "itemnumber": "A0002309911",
      "status": 3,
      "pagecount": 64,
      "orderstatus": 3,
      "requestedqty": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

**Expected output** :

```json
{
  "Header": {
    "Pagenumber": "1",
    "Countryid": "7002",
    "First Page": "true",
    "Last Page": "false",
    "countryId": 675,
    "dealerNumber": 675000,
    "Total Pages": "64" //(PAGE COUNT)
  },
  "TRANS-DETAILS": [
    {
      "customernum": "41700013",
      "crmordernum": "SO-000048949",
      "customerordernum": "Over delivery BRAZI",
      "itemnumber": "A0002309953",
      "status": 3,
      "orderstatus": 3,
      "requestedqty": 0
    },
    {
      "customernum": "41700013",
      "crmordernum": "SO-000048949",
      "customerordernum": "Over delivery BRAZI",
      "itemnumber": "A0002309953",
      "status": 3,
      "orderstatus": 3,
      "requestedqty": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The `"PAGECOUNT:64"` should only show in the header part, not in the element.Please help. Thanks

Comment: What's the logical relationship between the values of the attributes of `Header` vs.`TRANS-DETAILS` except for `Total Pages` ?

Comment: Output should contain Header and the Elements. Trans-detail is nothing but the child element header. Header contains some information with Static and non static value.

Comment: There is no relation other than Total Pages needs to include in the header from Transdetails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation specs

```json
[
  { // generate an extra attribute to represent the key of the array in order 
    // to be able to process within the next specs 
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "ttl",
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  { // get the uppercase title
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "ttl": "=toUpper(@(1,&))"
    }
  },
  { // replace of the array's title with uppercase form of it
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "tr*": "@1,ttl"
    }
  },
  { // take pagecount to an outer object, namely "Header"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "pagecount": "Header.Total Pages",
          "*": {
            "@": "&3[&2].&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only one(the first) Total Pages value 
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "Header": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  { // add the attributes with fixed values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Header": {
        "Pagenumber": "1",
        "Countryid": "7002",
        "First Page": "true",
        "Last Page": "false",
        "countryId": 675,
        "dealerNumber": 675000
      }
    }
  },
  { // sort the objects in alphabetical order
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

Comment: My current spec:

Comment: Hi Thanks. Each objects are coming with Numbering outside  :  say for an example "0":{ ...},"1"{....} {"Header" : .....}

Comment: Hi @SATHK . If your real input is exactly as I fixed, then they won't come like that, but exactly as the fixed expected output. eg. are you sure those input and expected output are true with respect to your original case ? I fixed them since they were not valid ...